# How to use the same session in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using python and selenium to develop a scrapy program. The website that I want to **scrape** required login before any action can be taken.  Every time it ask me to login to my account when I was running my program. I figured out by adding cookie it make the browser remember my session, but unfortunately it still cannot be login. Can anyone guide with the code? Thanks

My code:

```
import pickle
import time
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#product URL

driver.get("www.//xxx123.com/xxx")

driver.add_cookie({'domain': '.xxx123.com', 'expiry': 1677743964, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_ga','path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'GA1.1.203675790.1614671945'})
```

Comment: It might be simpler to use selenium to automate the login process: look for the input elements for the username and password, send the right characters, click the 'login' button.

Comment: @joao i was thinking about this too. But it have OTP to the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a Chrome driver, you should know that, each time you launch it, it creates a temporary profile that is deleted when you close it.

Depending on the webpage you are trying to **scrape**, recovering session data from cookies might be a challenge. It might be easier to create a profile first and re-use it as long as it lets you for persistence purposes.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

The path to your Chrome's profile should be available here: `chrome://version/`

In my experience, it is better to create a method that handles the login for you. Try to detect an element in the Login page; if it's not there, proceed as usual. If it is, perform a Login.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are alot directory in my path. Which one should i get ?

Comment: @Johnnyyy I'd use the Default one. Mine looks like this: Profile Path: C:\Users\Jose-Miguel.PEREZ-RO\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default